# How to spread elements of an array into keys of a dictionary? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

And i want to spread the elements 1,2,3,4 into keys of a dict so that I get

```py
_dict = {1:None, 2:None, 3:None, 4:None}
```

How can I do it more efficiently than:

```py
for el in a:
    _dict[el] = None
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.fromkeys) method:

```py
d = dict.fromkeys(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
_dict = {key: None for key in a}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign new values to a dict by typing `dict[key] = value`
The best way I can think of doing this is

```py
dict = {key: None for key in a}
# Or
for key in a:
    dict[key] = None
```

Comment: You have both duplicated the answer by [@MaBekitsur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205507/9758194) and the option OP has used =)

Comment: This is a pretty simple solution so it makes sense other people would come up with the same thing. Also at the same time as posting this answer no one else had commented on the post from what I could see. :)

Comment: Yeah I think it's unfortunate. Sometimes a refresh would help. People are quick at answering. I just noticed yours is the exact same, so effectively a dupe and therefor not adding value to the thread per se. Up to you offcourse if you would want to delete it.